# HTML Table with multiple rows header fixed and columns fixed

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have html table as below;

https://jsfiddle.net/supun151515/fwL8ut4k/

http://jsfiddle.net/supun151515/AC725/16/ -->jquery plugin

I want to make headers fixed and first 7 columns fixed.
I have tried with many jQuery plugins even pure CSS;

```
tbody {
 float: left; display: block; overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 100px;
}
tr {
float: left; display: block;
}
td {
float: left; display: block;
}
```

Nothing worked for me. Any good jQuery plugin to work with multiple rows header or pure CSS is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a table where only the columns scroll horizontally and headers remain fixed, you can `

> `position: absolute`

the first 7 columns and your row header (and specify their width explicitly), and then wrap the entire table in an
 `overflow-x: scroll` block.

Here is an example for your reference :

> https://jsfiddle.net/RMarsh/bzuasLcz/3/

Comment: I am using multi rows header, check your fiddle with my updated table structure. The table should looks like as shown in picture http://imgur.com/a/yapMq

Comment: Your example is close to what I am trying to accomplish. How do you fix multiple columns? Say, the first four columns, for example? While keeping the header also fixed.